# "CompareToIgnoreCase" no funciona

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un programa que me compare atributos y me retornen el valor (-1, 0, 1) cuando mis atributos sean o no iguales.

Este es mi código del método:

```
public int Comparar(CostosImpl CostosRef, CostosImpl CostosHerr, boolean cotizar) {

    if(CostosRef.getConcepto().equalsIgnoreCase(CostosHerr.getConcepto())) {

        if(CostosRef.getReferencia().equalsIgnoreCase(CostosHerr.getReferencia())) {

            if(CostosRef.getReferencia().equalsIgnoreCase("1000")) {

            int equals = CostosRef.getDescripcion().compareToIgnoreCase(CostosHerr.getDescripcion());
            if(equals == 0) {
                equals = CostosRef.getNumeroParte().compareToIgnoreCase(CostosHerr.getNumeroParte());
                if(equals == 0) {
                    if(!cotizar) {
                        return Double.compare(CostosRef.getMonto(), CostosHerr.getMonto());
                    }
                }
                return equals;
            } else
                return equals;
             }
        }
        else {
            int equals = CostosRef.getReferencia().compareToIgnoreCase(CostosHerr.getReferencia());
            if(equals == 0) {
                if(!cotizar) {
                    return Double.compare(CostosRef.getMonto(), CostosHerr.getMonto());
                }
            }
            return equals;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Es simple, al inicio solo valida si "Concepto" y "Referencia" son iguales, , si "Referencias" son iguales, se procede a checar si el valor es 1000 y de ahí más proceso...
Mi problema en sí, es que mi programa DEBE retonarme un valor 0 si losa atributos "Concepto" y "Referencia" son iguales.

Estos son mis atributos:

```
CostosRef.setConcepto("Refaccion");
        CostosRef.setReferencia("1000");
        CostosRef.setMonto(150);
        CostosRef.setDescripcion("ABISAG.SUP.PUER.TRA.D");
        CostosRef.setNumeroParte("67550T9d3AT00ZZ");

        CostosHerr.setConcepto("Refaccion");
        CostosHerr.setReferencia("1000");
        CostosHerr.setMonto(150);
        CostosHerr.setDescripcion("cABISAG.SUP.PUER.TRA.D");
        CostosHerr.setNumeroParte("67550T9d3AT00ZZ");
```

Como pueden ver, "Referencia" y "Concepto" coinciden, y espero que me retorne un valor 0 y no lo hace, me regresa un negativo.

¿Qué podría agregar?.

Gracias.

Comment: Parece solamente un problema de desorden de tu codigo. Este if: if(CostosRef.getReferencia().equalsIgnoreCase("1000")) { No hace nada, ya que abre y cierra llaves sin hacer realmente algo. probaste debuguear tu codigo?

Comment: @gbianchi tienes razón, ya corregí esa llave, aún no lo debugeo.

Comment: debuguearlo es el primer paso para encontrar el error y saber por donde sale.

Comment: @gbianchi ya lo hice pero sigo sin comprender el porque no me lo arroja en 0 si son iguales las referencias y conceptos...

Comment: Si seguis tu codigo, nunca pero nunca estas devolviendo cero. Seguro hiciste un debug y fuiste paso a paso por tu codigo? esto es solamente un error de logica en tu codigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solamente es un problema que vos podes solucionar.. Miremos las 3 primeras lineas de tu codigo:

```
if(CostosRef.getConcepto().equalsIgnoreCase(CostosHerr.getConcepto())) {
    if(CostosRef.getReferencia().equalsIgnoreCase(CostosHerr.getReferencia())) {
        if(CostosRef.getReferencia().equalsIgnoreCase("1000")) {
```

En este punto, ya sabes que los conceptos son iguales, que las referencias son iguales, y que la referencia es 1000. Entonces aca deberias devolver el 0. Pero tu codigo, sigue haciendo cosas cuando llega a este punto.

Lo que tenes que hacer es revisar tu codigo y seguirlo paso a paso.

Comment: Listo, tienes razón, solamente era verificar bien los pasos del código y parte de la lógica, muchas gracias!